# mod_rewrite Allow only one file and restrict the others

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(allow\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /allow.php/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MYUSERAGENT [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12.12\.12\.12$
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com [R=302,L]
```

I wrote this code for restricting access to my page. But I want everybody to access allow.php
This code is not working it still redirects.
Why is that happening?

Comment: I think the $1 part is your problem. Try using `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead

Comment: Then I am getting allow.php loop. net/allow.php/allow.php/allow.php/....

Comment: It shouldn't do that. The string `!^allow\.php` means all request URI's NOT STARTING WITH allow.php. Have you tested with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^allow\.php`?

Comment: Yes, getting loop again

Comment: Sorry about that. you ned a starting slash before allow.php: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/allow\.php` You also should have mentioned the need for handling `sub.php` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sub\.php - [L,NC]

# if not sub.php, not desired user agent and not your IP then redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MYUSERAGENT [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12.12\.12\.12$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: When I go directly to the site it redirects me /allow.php/
When I go allow.php it redirects /allow.php/allow.php

Comment: What is `sub.php`? Your code mentioned `allow.php`. Show your complete .htaccess in question

Comment: Allow.php and sub.php are the same, I just wanted to tell understandable in my question

Comment: That's all I just changed user agent,redirect url and php's name.

Comment: Still same goes to php no matter what.

Comment: Test it in a different browser. `/allow.php` should remain unchanged. Remember to copy/paste the rule as it is from my answer.

Comment: Sorry but still same. Goes to /allow.php/ 
Same from local, allowed user-agent, other user-agents

Comment: Check updated code and **copy paste as is** to your .htaccess and test in separate browser. This code is tested and working on my Apache.

Comment: Of course `katates.sytes.net` will goto `katates.sytes.net/sub.php` that was what your rule was also doing. Looks like you didn't explain the requirement clearly. I made a change in the code as per my understanding. If it is not what you want, please clarify the requirements.

Comment: I have a page, I want to access it from my phone (specific user agent) and my computer (local). I also want everyone to access .net/sub.php without permission.

Comment: ok in that case above rule should work fine for you. (test in separate browser.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MYUSERAGENT [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12.12\.12\.12$
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com [R=302,L]
```

Since the rewrite engine will loop and the rewritten `/allow.php/something/something` will the hit the second rule and get redirected.

Comment: Is it impossible what I want to do?